# Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm using getter to display data fetched using wire service in lwc html and getting and error :

**Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined**

Below is the piece of code:

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Basic Wire Example!"></lightning-card>
    <p>Account Name : {accountName}</p>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement , api, wire} from 'lwc';
import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import Name from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
export default class WireBasic extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord , {recordId : '$recordId', fields: [Name]}) record;
    get accountName(){
        return this.record.data.fields.Name.value;
    }
}
```

The error is actually triggered from get **accountName**. I used so many console logs to understand the order of execution and understand that **connectedcallback** is called before **wire** and maybe **getter** too is being called before wire assigns the value to **record**.
Is there a way to ensure that getter isn't called till a value is assigned by wire? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`record` is a method, not a property. Given your current code, you could just:

```
get accountName() {
  return this.sAcctName;
}
```

The only time you'd use `this.record.data...` would be if you used the wire annotation as a property:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [Name]) record;
```

...

```
get accountName() {
    return this.record && this.record.data.fields.Name.value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I understand that it's a method and that was a miss from my end. However, I'm still getting the same error when I change it back to a property. Updated my code.

Comment: @AshutoshArora As I demonstrated near the end, check to see if `this.record` is populated first: `return this.record && this.record.data.fields.Name.value`

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't fix the error.

Comment: I commented out {accountName} from template and added a button which calls a js method.. I used console.log('?? : ',this.record.data.fields.Name.value) to see if this prints the value.. this actually works, I am able to see the account name in console.. Can this be because getters are called before wire executes?

Comment: @AshutoshArora What about getFieldValue? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value

Comment: getFieldValue() does the trick.. but I'm not able to understand why the other approach was not working? The documentation too specifies that approach. any idea abou that?

Comment: @AshutoshArora Honestly, I'm not sure. It should work. I'll have to experiment later. At least you have a solution that works. I'd recommend getFieldValue anyways, as it's shorter than the alternative.